# How to pause side-by-side figures with their position fixed in beamer?

Tags: beamer, minipage, pause

I am trying to pause figures in the beamer.

Basically, I am using minipage to make figures side by side.

I want to use pause so that I can show the first figure and then the second.

Below is the sample code I have

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{../figures/graph1.eps}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{../figures/graph2.eps}<2->
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I show the first figure only, the figure is not on the left but is placed at the center of the slide.

So I was wondering how should I fix the code in order to keep the first figure on the left?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `MWE` is working fine for me, can you please remove `\centering` and then try...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\visible` to make sure the image still occupies space on the first overlay:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\visible<2->{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```